# Facebook Share URL no longer works!!?? Alternative?

Tags: facebook, share

This was working fine until today.  Has anybody had this just stop working for no apparant reason?  I have not changed any of my code.  I had left it for about a month so it's just the raw test pages that I had created to test it.  But when I went to implement it, it has just stopped working!!  Should I be using something else?  Please see HTML below.

Cheers,
J

Page to display button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>

</head>

<?PHP

    $micro = microtime();
    $id = "35";

    print '<a name="fb_share" type="button_count" share_url="http://www.takeitoffme.com/test/staticadvert/staticadvert.php?id='.$id.'&time='.$micro.'"href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>';


?>

<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
```

The above uses micro time to make the URL unique to prevent caching.
Page called:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the title"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="This is the description"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://takeitoffme.com/test/images/towelie.jpg"/>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>


<FORM action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?id=' . $advertid; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    



</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, below URL still works fine.

http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=URL

Try to rawurlencode your URL before send it as a parameter

Comment: Hi,  Unfortunately it doesn't work as I'd expect it to.  Not sure why but it doesn't seem to be picking up the meta data on the called page???  Used:  http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.takeitoffme.com/test/staticadvert/staticadvert.php?id=35&time=0.092230001320800564

Comment: Actually, just noticed in the description that it IS in fact using cached information.  How can this be possible?  I've manually tweaked the data sent after the ? bit and it still brings up the cached page!!??